# Why mysql hit index when column wrap with date function

Tags: mysql

IMO, the below mysql will not hit index when the add_time field wrap with the date() func, but from the explain result, it hit index, why?

```
explain 
SELECT count(0) 
FROM xxx 
WHERE  date(add_time) >= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day);
```

[image]

Comment: What's the type of the column `add_time`? If the type is `DATE` then the function has no effect and the SQL parser may have simplified the condition to `add_time >= ...` during the rewriting phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EXPLAIN report is known to be hard to interpret. They have overloaded too much information into a few fields. You might try

The `type: index` indicates it's doing an *index-scan*, which means it's visiting every entry in the index.

This visits the same number of entries as a table-scan, except it's against a secondary index instead of the clustered (primary) index.

When we see `type: index`, EXPLAIN shows `possible_keys: NULL` which means it can't use any index for searching efficiently. But it also shows `key: add_time` which means the index it's using for the index-scan is `add_time`.

The index-scan is due to the fact that MySQL cannot optimize expressions or function calls by itself. For example, if you were to try to search for dates with a specific month, you could search for `month(add_time) = 4` but that wouldn't use the index on add_time because the dates with that month are scattered through the index, not all grouped together.

You may know that `date(add_time)` should be able to be searched by the index, but MySQL does not make that inference. MySQL just sees that you're using a function, and it doesn't even try to use the index.

That's why MySQL 5.7 introduced [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to allow us to index an expression, and MySQL 8.0 made it even better by allowing an [index to defined for an expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) without requiring us to define a generated column first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misinterpreting the explain plan here.  If you look under `possible_keys`, you will see that it is `NULL`.  From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) on explain output format:

> If this column is NULL (or undefined in JSON-formatted output), there are no relevant indexes.

So, the index which is being used as mentioned in the `Extra` section probably has nothing to do with `add_time`.

Comment: I think it actually may be using the secondary index instead of the clustering index, as a "full index scan" operation. It seems this index may be a "covering index", but I'm not sure. MySQL plans are not 100% clear to me.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm also not completely sure which index is being used...given that it's just a count query, MySQL could just as easily scan an index as scan the entire table.  The point of my answer was just the index was not being used in the way the OP thinks it is.